# How can Coffeescript 2 be treated as JSX? (Webpack/Babel)

Tags: reactjs, coffeescript, jsx, babeljs

Coffeescript 2 allows JSX/XML to be included directly into the language. How can I get Babel (I think it's Babel's job) to both compile the Coffeescript to Javascript AND the resulting JSX to Javascript?

Preferably I'd like to do this with just a `.coffee` extension.

Comment: Babel should be able to handle both if you have the right plugins/presets installed. Just point it at the `.coffee` files and it should work.

Answer (score 2):

Babel doesn’t work with CoffeeScript directly; you first need to use the CoffeeScript compiler to turn the `.coffee` files into JSX. Then Babel can take that and transpile it down to JavaScript.

If you haven’t already, install Babel with whatever plugins you want to use, for example:

```
npm install --save-dev babel-core babel-preset-env babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx
```

Create a `.babelrc` file to configure Babel:

```
echo '{ "presets": ["env"], "plugins": ["transform-react-jsx"] }' > .babelrc
```

Then the simplest option is to use the `coffee` command with `--transpile`, which will include Babel transpilation:

```
coffee --compile --transpile --inline-map some-file.coffee
```

The resulting `some-file.js` will be runnable JavaScript. See http://coffeescript.org/#transpilation